# WCF service throw error when reading from Stream - An exception has been thrown when reading the stream

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wcf, wcf-rest

Hello This is my service code - I want to read XMl which is passed by client but while start reading its throw error - An exception has been thrown when reading the stream.

```
    [WebMethod]
    public bool processEvent(Stream XMLDoc)
    {
        string logPath = string.Empty;
        processEventResult result = new processEventResult();
        try
        {
            logPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServiceLogPath"];

            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(XMLDoc))
            {
                while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                {
                    string xmlString = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
                    xDoc.LoadXml(xmlString);
                    string returnValue = xDoc.OuterXml;
                }
            }
        }
     }

 public interface IDMSService
   {
    [OperationContract(Action = "urn:ProcessEvent")]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "processEvent",BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml)]
    processEventResult processEvent(Stream XMLDoc);
  }
```

Comment: surely you dont want to create a new xml doc and reload just a small random chunk of xml for each packet?

Comment: What exception are you getting? If you're just trying to get the XML as a string why bother loading it into an `XmlDocument`, you could just use `reader.ReadToEnd()`. If you still want to load the XmlDocument, use the [Load(Stream) Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e48zttz7(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I am getting error on same line reader.ReadToEnd() - exception An exception has been thrown when reading the stream

Comment: I just want to read all content of strem

Comment: I just want to read all content of stream - Inner Exception -Start element processEvent from namespace '' expected. Found element processEvent from namespace  www.test.com Line 3, position 69.

Comment: Can you post the `<serviceModel>` section of your config, as well as the code where you call the service?